# Pass constant parameters to function when using scipy minimize on more than one parameter

Tags: python, scipy

I have a least squares error function (based on another function) that I'd like to minimize (to obtain a globally minimized curve fit, basically), which looks something like this:

```
def err(a, b, X, Y):
    return np.sum((f(a, b, X)-Y)**2)
```

with `X` being an array of points at which `f` is evaluated, depending on the parameters `a` and `b`, and `Y` being the "ground truth" for the points defined in `X`.

Now according to what I found in questions [25206482](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206482/using-scipy-to-minimize-a-function-that-also-takes-non-variational-parameters) and [31388319](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388319/passing-args-in-scipy-optimize-minimize-objective-function-getting-error-on-nu) the syntax should be as follows:

```
Xc = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])   # points at which to evaluate error function
Yc = np.array([0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.12, 0.15]) # ground truth
g0 = np.array([1.0, 3.0])                  # initial guess for a and b    
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(err, g0, args=(Xc, Yc), method="Powell")
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: err() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

If I delete `Xc` or `Yc` from the tuple, the number of arguments given decreases, so I suspect it is somewhere in the definition of `g0`, because this seems to be passed to `err` as a single argument.

How do I call `minimize` properly if I have more than one parameter for optimization and additional "constant" arguments I want to pass to my function during optimization?

Comment: Test your setup with `err(g0, Xc, Yc)` - that evaluates your function as the initial guess.  If that fails then you need to change `err` or the `args` tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minimize` manipulates only a single parameter, but this can be an array. What you have to do is extract `a` and `b` from the first parameter in `err`:

```
def err(p, X, Y):
    a, b = p
    return np.sum((f(a, b, X)-Y)**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that minimizing works if I define the error function such that it uses a list of parameters instead of several parameters:

```
def err(p, X, Y):
    a = p[0]
    b = p[1]
    return np.sum((f(a, b, X)-Y)**2)
```

and then call `minimize`:

```
g0 = [1.0, 3.0]
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(err, g0, args=(Xc, Yc), method="Powell")
```