# Passing constants and variables into Scipy.minimize.optimize constraints and boundaries

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, optional-arguments

I found how one can pass `*args` into the main function of `scipy.minimize.optimize`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25206482/8069403).

But how do I pass constants and variables into constraints and boundaries?

`P` is a variable vector, `P0` is the initial solution vector, `f(P)` is the function to minimize, the rest are constant data. Will it work like this?

```
def constraint_1(P, args):
    M_goal, other_args = args
    M = calc_M_from_P(P, args)  # calculate M from P
    return M-M_goal

# boundary is simply (P0[i]-500, P0[i]+500)
def get_boundaries(P0): 
    list_bnds = []
    for i in range(len(P0)):
        list_bnds.append((P0[i]-500.0, P0[i]+500.0))
    return tuple(list_bnds)

func = objective(P0, args)
bnds = get_boundaries(P0)
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_1}

sol = minimize(func, P0, args = args, method='SLSQP', bound=bnds, constraints = con1)
```

Comment: Your link is broken. For obtaining the right address of a StackOverflow question or answer, pleas click on the **share** under it.

Comment: "Constraints for COBYLA, SLSQP are defined as a list of dictionaries [...] with fields: [...] args : sequence, optional". What part of this is unclear?